# {Structure:page:entry_id} ouput order

Tags: structure

I want to output all siblings of an item using the same order as displayed in structure, the following code works but I need to be able to do this dynamically as I can't hardcode the parent id for each page this is required on

```
{exp:structure:entries parent_id="52"} output here {/exp:structure:entries}
```

I then changed the code to this:

```
{exp:structure:entries parent_id="{structure:page:entry_id}"} output here {/exp:structure:entries}
```

and it works, but the output's order is reversed, no idea why this happens, is there anyway to make the order correct, as per the first example?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Are you running the latest version of Structure? It should output the list fine in your first example. Start a support thread with us if not.

Comment: Running EE 2.8 and Structure 3.3.14, as per my post it does work fine in the first example, but when {structure:page:entry_id} is added into the mix it's reversed.